# Make a beat machine in js

Tags: javascript

I wanna make a beat machine to play sounds at a given time. I need to pass in a bpm number. My first attempt was just to use a setInterval function to get a constant beat, but Im not sure if thats the way to go.

```
let beat = (bpm) => {

  setInterval(()=> {

    // Run update beat machine

  }, (60 * 1000) / bpm)
}
```

I didnt find anything on the web. I appreciate articles as well.
thanks

Comment: what's the problem?

Comment: @DCR It's pretty clear from the question that they don't know if this is the correct approach or not.  (It isn't.)

Answer (score 0):

No, that's not what you want.  `setInterval` is not precise.

The Web Audio API has an [AudioBufferSourceNode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AudioBufferSourceNode) which keeps the sample in memory.  It can be scheduled to start at a certain time.

```
bufferNode.start(0.5, startOffset);
```

In this example, we start playing 0.5 seconds from the offset.

Comment: The AudioBufferSourceNode is only for samples right? Because Im having a Oscillator and I found a Article about a little sequencer which starts the osc and then stops it at a given time again. osc.start(); osc.stop(context.currentTime + length);. But im getting the following error:  Failed to execute 'start' on 'AudioScheduledSourceNode': cannot call start more than once.

Comment: @Fluqz Correct, and you can only start them once.  See the documentation:  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AudioBufferSourceNode  "An AudioBufferSourceNode can only be played once; after each call to start(), you have to create a new node if you want to play the same sound again. Fortunately, these nodes are very inexpensive to create, and the actual AudioBuffers can be reused for multiple plays of the sound. Indeed, you can use these nodes in a "fire and forget" manner: create the node, call start() to begin playing the sound, and don't even bother to hold a reference to it."